# Filesystem "Operation not permitted", even as sudo

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems

I have a directory that I'm unable to perform any filesystem operation on.

I'll paste below the attempts I made to find the issue.

I tried `ls -al` and the permissions looked good.
I tried `getfacl` and the permissions looked good.
I tried `strace` and didn't see any information that would help point to the issue.

The directory is normal in every way that I can tell. Inside the directory, I have some subdirectories that some RAID volumes get mounted to. The mounts work. I can create files under `mnt/mymount/etc...` but I can't do anything at `mnt/`.

```
eihli@molavia:~$ mkdir mnt/foo
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘mnt/foo’: Operation not permitted

eihli@molavia:~$ touch mnt/foo
touch: setting times of 'mnt/foo': No such file or directory

eihli@molavia:~$ ls -al mnt
total 28
drwxr-xr-x   7 eihli eihli 4096 Sep  8 09:35 .
drwxr-xr-x  33 eihli eihli 4096 Oct 12 10:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 eihli eihli 4096 Sep  7 11:24 data
drwxrwsr-x+  5 eihli share 4096 Oct 12 10:39 hitraid
drwxr-xr-x   2 eihli eihli 4096 Aug 17 09:32 ssd1
drwxr-xr-x   2 eihli eihli 4096 Aug 22 13:04 usb
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root  4096 Sep  7 19:46 wd500raid

eihli@molavia:~$ sudo getfacl mnt
# file: mnt
# owner: eihli
# group: eihli
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

eihli@molavia:~$ strace touch mnt/foo
execve("/usr/bin/touch", ["touch", "mnt/foo"], 0x7fffdd2a6e28 /* 48 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55b68276e000
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "mnt/foo", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
utimensat(AT_FDCWD, "mnt/foo", NULL, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a file attribute: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/File_permissions_and_attributes#File_attributes

```
eihli@molavia:~$ lsattr .
----i---------e------- ./mnt
```

I haven't figured out what caused the directory to have that attr. The only possible things that I'm messing with that are unfamiliar to me that might be causing it are something to do with the RAID filesystems or with IPFS.